# iPad Chrome - Submit form in new Window/Tab not working

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, ipad, extjs

We develop c# .NET application, javascript and using EXTJS (6.0.2).
Application work fine with all browser at PC platforms
but for iPad Chrome we have problem with submit form in new window/tab
the new window/tab will not open.

here is code ...

```
test.init = function (config) {

    var submitButtonHandler = function (scope, eArgs) {
        var params = {
            q: 'test',
        };

        submitForm.submit({
            params: params
        });

    }


    var action = 'https://www.google.com/';
    var hiddenFormValues = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {});
    var submitForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'form',
            method: 'post',
            target: '_blank',
            action: action
        },
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Click to test',
            handler: submitButtonHandler,
            exportMethod: 'openhtml',
            xtype: 'TestButton'
        }],

        submit: function (config) {
            config.params = config.params || {};
            var keys = Object.keys(config.params);
            var html = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                var key = keys[i];
                var value = config.params[key];
                if (typeof (value) === "string") value = value.replace(/'/g, "&#39;");
                html += '<input type="hidden" name="' + key + '" value=\'' + value + '\'/>';
            }
            alert(html);
            hiddenFormValues.update(html);
            alert(this.id);
            document.getElementById(this.id).submit();
        }

    })

    return submitForm;
}
```

For PC chrome open the new tab window just fine

BUT for iPad chrome will not open then new/tab window, not working.

Any suggestions are appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
if (form.isValid()) {
  form.submit({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/WAR_project/rest/service/ticket/uploadfile',
    waitMsg: 'Uploading Please Wait...',
    method: 'POST',                    
    success: function (r, a) {
      console.log('success message here')
    },
    failure: function (r, a) {                    
      console.log('failure message here')
    }
  });
}
```